# Problems with the alternating rows color tags in the Tkinter Treeview. The rows are duplicated

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to alternate the color of the Treeview rows. I added the two tags with colors, but I added them with two inserts: it means I get the color of the alternative rows correctly, but obviously each row duplicates itself.

How can i insert two tags with colors in the same insert?

```
my_treeview.tag_configure('oddrow', background='white', foreground='black')
my_treeview.tag_configure('evenrow', background='gray', foreground='black')

    for key, value in dict.items():
        ...
        my_treeview.insert(parent='', index='end', tags=(('oddrow')), values=(datagrid))
        my_treeview.insert(parent='', index='end', tags=(('evenrow')), values=(datagrid))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to determine which tag is to be used.  One of the way is use the *index* of the current row:

```py
for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(dict.items()):
    ...
    tag = 'evenrow' if idx%2 == 0 else 'oddrow'
    my_treeview.insert(parent='', index='end', tags=(tag,), values=datagrid)
```

Note that it is not recommended to use `dict` as a variable name as it is a keyword.